# How to disable Hibernate checking for id value

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a table A that has `id` defined as the following:

```
    id BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_table_A PRIMARY KEY 
       DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR sequence_table_a),
```

I can not change this. In my Spring Boot application if I put `EntityA` with generated value or sequence generator on id, then Hibernate will not let me persist the new objects because SQL definition sees that I am trying to manually add id.
The *exception* is

```
SQL Error: 544, SQLState: S0001
2023-10-17 14:21:56.531 ERROR 35652 --- [   scheduling-1]
    o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : 
    Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table_a' 
    when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

If I remove the generated sequence annotations and just let `@Id`, Hibernate tells me that I need to manually set values (it does not see the default setting on the table).

How do I fix this?

Comment: try `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` but we need more details on code, annotations you use and errors you get

Comment: Could you update your question inserting EntityA? Just to have more details.